# When ogr2ogr hits rasters in a file geodatabase

Tags: gdal, ogr, esri-geodatabase

I would like to use ogr2ogr.py to batch convert feature classes and tables in a collection of ESRI file geodatabases into geopackages, but some of these gdbs have rasters in them, apparently in SDE format; there are four tables prefixed with fras_aux, fras_blk, fras_bnd, and fras_ras containing rows of blobs. I can't figure out how to make use of these once converted to geopackage tables. Is it possible to either get ogr2ogr to convert these into usable rasters or do it after the fact?

Comment: The Esri FileGeodatabase API doesn't attempt to support rasters, so there isn't even an API for it. Export the rasters to GeoTIFF with an ArcGIS client.

Comment: The non-Esri reverse engineered OpenFileGDB driver doesn't support rasters yet. You can however use an open source tool called [ArcRasterRescue](https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue) to extract them to GeoTIFFs. It's only provided as source code (C++) which you need to compile to an executable yourself. Very simple to do in Linux, not so much in Windows.

Comment: And note that `ogr2ogr` is for vector data, `gdal_translate` is for raster data.

Comment: Thanks all. I didn't have much hope for an ogr2ogr or driver-specific solution. And my other question about reconstructing the converted tables seems to be answered by the existence of ArcRasterRescue which suggests that the storage of raster data in a fgdb is more opaque than the resulting "fras_" tables imply.